# PHP SimpleXML - Get Attribute Values - Loop

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

i don't know why am I not getting all results what i want from the xml file.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://2strok.com/gen/maler.xml") or 
     die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $books) { 
    echo $books->XResult->Contacts->XContact->Name . "<br>";
    echo $books->XResult->Contacts->XContact->Value . "<br>"; 
    echo $books->XResult->Contacts->XContact->VisitationAddress . "
    <br>"; 
            } 
?>
```

I'm using php foreach but i'm getting only the first line :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://2strok.com/gen/maler.xml") or
     die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->ResultList->XResult as $res) {
    if ($res->Contacts->XContact) {
        echo $res->Contacts->XContact->Name . "<br>";
        echo $res->Contacts->XContact->Value . "<br>";
        echo $res->Contacts->XContact->VisitationAddress . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Or this, if you want all contacts :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://2strok.com/gen/maler.xml") or
     die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->ResultList->XResult as $res) {
    foreach ($res->Contacts->XContact as $elm) {
        echo $elm->Name . "<br>";
        echo $elm->Value . "<br>";
        echo $elm->VisitationAddress . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... the the second one was perfect ;) LOVE YA

Comment: @Zabi You're welcome. Please, you could close your question is it helps. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Thanks :)

Comment: I need to wait a little bit, cuz i can't vote it that fast :D

Comment: I was actually talking about that one too :P

Comment: I do have one more question from you Mr @Syscall.. how can i get the Coordinate->lat and lot ? i tried all ways but not any sucsess :S

Comment: @Zabi `$res->Contacts->XContact->Coordinate->Lat` for the first case, and `$elm->Coordinate->Lat` for the second. The same for `lon` :)